# Print Message At a particular time when Time sleep is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was trying to print a message when `time.sleep` is running , For ex - if `time.sleep` is enabled for 10 second I want to print a message when 5 second have passed for this I was trying below syntax but not getting what I needed

```
import time 

c =  10

for i in range(c,0,-1):
    time.sleep(c)
   
    print(i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
    if i == 5 :
        print(i )
        break
```

Comment: You probably want to sleep 1second I  each loop, not `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by

```
import time
import sys

for remaining in range(10, 0, -1):
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    if remaining == 5:
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write("\rComplete!            \n")
```